# Consolidated View of Interface Statusses

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, dashboard

We are in process of designing different interfaces for our system. We need to pull information from 3rd party systems into our own system which runs on SQL Server 2008 R2.

We want to be able to view the "status" of each interface (success/fail/datetime) in one place like a dashboard. Kind of a birds eye view of all the interface statusses. Could be around 10 interfaces, maybe showing a red/green robot as status and when you hover or click it give a bit more info. it could also have the functionality (a button) to re-run the interface immediately from the dashboard.

Interface details are sketchy at this stage, but the following is true:
- A number of records will be inserted into some SQL Server table from a source object (could be csv/direct sql/SSIS etc)
- Interfaces might run realtime/daily or hourly
- We can use SSRS or maybe Tableau/clickview for dashboard/display.

I just wanted to know if anyone as any experience with this type of thing, or have maybe done it before, who could give some tips or guidance or point me to examples on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit biased toward SSRS, as I've used it extensively over the last few years. But for what you describe, SSRS will easily be able to handle your dashboard needs.

I can't say I've built a dashboard for your particular scenario, but I've written scores of reports with SSRS in a dashboard style and haven't had any major complaints.

Comment: I have been using SSRS for a while now to write reports for our company. I guess there is a lot more to SSRS, ie dashboarding? What tool do you use to actually create the dashboards as I only use MS visual Studio > Report server project (BI) for the reports.

Comment: We use SharePoint extensively, and the enterprise edition of SharePoint comes with SSRS reporting services and SSRS Report Builder. And we in the organization that have VS author reports that way as well. Most of what I'm asked to make are scheduled reports that are simple tables of data (grouped/sorted, etc), but occasionally have to make a dashboard (KPIs, charts, etc). It's a great medium for either.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try some other tools besides the ones you've mentioned already, especially if it's not perfectly clear what the final requirements will be; for example, you may want to try a tool which is easier to use, like [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), which let you design a dashboard with pure drag and drop from query to final design, and yet, if you're a power user, let's you tweak the query easily without the need to jump hooks.

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.